# Learning about NSNumber

Tags: nsstring, nsnumber, iboutlet

if I`m getting a string from IBOutlet I use:

```
NSString *stringName = [[self IBOutletName] text];
```

but how can I get a value if it`s a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
NSString * someNumberString = [[self IBOutletName] text];
int someInt = [someNumberString intValue];
```

Note, I'm sure there are more, but just asa starter, you can also use:

```
float someFloat = [someFloatString floatValue]; // for floats
double someDouble = [someDoubleString doubleValue]; // for doubles
```

If you want the string value from an NSNumber just do:

```
NSString * stringValue = [someNSNumber stringValue];
```

Comment: Hi Logan, I`m looking for the same what "text" does to [[self IBOutletName] text], but for NSNumber.
I`ve tried **number* and **float* but did`t work. Any idea? =)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking.  Are you saying you're trying to get the string value of a NSNumber? If so, just call string value NSString* someString = [someNSNumber stringValue];

Comment: There is an IBOutlet in main.storyboard that should receive a number., the user should insert a number. I need to get this number from it.

Comment: Have you connected your IBOutlet to it's ViewController file? If so, and your IBOutlet is named textInput, do int input =  [self.textInput.text intValue]; // changing 'int' if floats etc. are options

Comment: Yes, I did, but look:
- (IBAction)calc:(id)sender {
    NSNumber *superHeight = [self.height.text floatValue];
} error: initializing 'NSNumber *_strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'float'

Comment: Change: NSNumber *superHeight = [self.height.text floatValue]; to NSNumber *superHeight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self.height.text floatValue]];

Comment: EXCELLENT!!! Thank you very much Logan and sorry for the way I explained it.. This is all new for me!

Comment: Everybody's gotta start somewhere, good luck with your project!